# Why am I not able to get the data() value of my autocomplete input field?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, attributes

I'm using jQuery autocomplete on the following input

`<input data-searchurl="Some url" />`

But when I try to retrieve the data value `searchurl`, I get `undefined`.
Hmm... I get the same if I try using `attr` as well.

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: function (request) {
        var url = $(this).data('searchurl');
        (...)
```

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/34ewgg7j/3/

Why is autocomplete preventing me from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(this.element).data('searchurl')` and it works, that will point to each individual input in the collection, if you have multiple inputs in the selector.

Comment: Maybe elaborate why it works? ;) From Dima: "Inside a widget, "this" refers to the widget object itself, wich contains a property "element" that points to html element for wich that widget has been applied.". Src: http://bit.ly/104W44E